# Steps to test iphone app on device (profile/certificate already created)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, ios

I want to test my app on my itouch which has ios 4.2.1 .

I have completed the steps for provisioning profile/certificate. So under Organizer,
when I select my device, I am seeing the provisioning profile
and under Developer profile, I see 2 entries; iPhone Developer and iPhone Distributor

Now I want to just test the app on my device (NOT looking for steps to submit the app for distribution at this stage)

I think there are some Project settings that I need to do under XCode. But I am unable to figure it out. Please provide me the steps to test on device.
My XCode ver is 3.2.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Double click your app under targets in Xcode
2. Make sure that for the configuration 'Development' you have the right development provisioning 
   profiles selected.
3. click on the properties tag and make sure that the identifier is the same as the identifier used in
   the development profile.

clean all targets, in Xcode make sure you are building for Device, Debug, and than click 'build and run'.

If the development profile is on your iPhone and you have installed it into Xcode correctly it should work. However sometimes after installing a profile on your iPhone it doesn't register everywhere it needs to and I have found that this is fixed by restarting the iPhone (not Xcode).

Good luck.

Comment: I could not find the configuration 'Development' . Also for step 3, can the same identifier be used for multiple apps ? What exactly does it signify?

Comment: If you could not find the configuration Development than you should create one in the configurations tab.  Regarding step 3, you can only use the identifier that was used when creating the profile (ie. com.yourcompany.yourapp)

Answer (score 1):

I was hitting an issue following this and the documentation where my app would not deploy to my iPhone 3G running iOS 4.2.1 using XCode 4.2.  I hope this helps others who end up on this question trying to get their apps to deploy to a real device through XCode.

I kept fiddling with the Base SDK setting along with the Deployment Target setting in the project and target settings area.  However, I had them correct to start with so that wasn't the answer (I want to target iOS 3.2+, so I kept all set to that).  In addition, I messed with the provisioning profiles, certificates, etc. multiple times even though they looked right to me.  They weren't the issue, either.

The key was changing the architecture settings that are scattered throughout the interface.

1. First, since I am testing it on an iPhone 3G, I needed to support the armv6 architecture as well as armv7 for later models.  So I added "armv6" to the "Valid Architectures" entry on the project's "Build Settings" tab.
2. Next, I made sure it was showing "armv6 armv7" under "Architectures" in the "Build Settings" tab of the target for my project.
3. Finally, I clicked on the -Info.plist file for my project and removed the "armv7" entry for the "Required device capabilities" that is put there by default for new projects in XCode 4.2.

After this, my app ran successfully on the device using Command + R for Run.