# iOS Application Testing on real device

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am using Xcode 6.1 ,  first time I am using this . My application is completed .
My development target is 7.0 and my mac OS is 10.10.2 Yosemite . I want to test my application on real device . please anybody tell me the best process which I will follow .

Comment: Get a device and development account for generating the provisioning profile, add to your XCode and run the app, also google so many times and differents ways because its so common question and can not be ask here.

Comment: first please research, if any answer not available then ask the question...there is lots of stuff on internet on this...check that out..

Comment: i provide you one link...checked it out http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-test-your-app-on-an-ios-device--mobile-13861

Comment: Do you know google ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Steps to test iphone app on device (profile/certificate already created)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210477/steps-to-test-iphone-app-on-device-profile-certificate-already-created)

Comment: @DavidAnsermot My boss used to tell me this line whenever I stuck into any problem :)

Comment: As i am using xcode 6.1 and deployment target is 7.0 with lates mac os 10.10 so is there any issue

Comment: I'm just gonna be a jerk and, for your own sake, link this :http://tinyurl.com/kpm3jvu

Comment: This is not a perfect  solution

Answer (score 0):

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Testing_Apps_on_iOS_7_Devices_with_Xcode_5
Adding a Device to the Developer Portal
Running an Application on a Registered Device
ttps://developer.apple.com/membercenter for creating signing codes

Comment: there is no issue on that...you need to just register your device with apple..just follow the step from link and you done it...just try my friend